# Ordinal logistic regression with random variable and quantitative predictor variable

Tags: r, random, mixed-models, cumulative-sum, ordinal

I want to use an ordinal logistic regression (my response variable is ordinal) that works with 2 random variables and for quantitative predictor variable with interaction (my formula is: `ordinal_variable~ quantitative_variable:habitat + (1|community) + (1|species)`.

I was analyzing my data with `clmm` (see the script below) and got the results I expected, however I noticed that `clmm` was designed to be used when response and predictor variables are factorial.

I then tried the `polmer` (see the script below), but I did not get any answers.

Would someone have any suggestions on how to analyze this data?

```
library(ordinal)
model1 <- clmm(as.factor(ordinal_variable)~ 
     quantitative_variable:habitat + (1|community) + (1|species), 
     data=baseline)
summary(model1)
```

```
library(MPDiR)
library(lme4)
model2 <- polmer(as.factor(ordinal_variable) ~ 

    quantitative_variable:habitat + (community - 1 | Obs) + 
    (species - 1 | Obs),           data=baseline)
summary(model2)
```

Comment: your problem with `clmm` isn't at all clear to me. The response variable does need to be an *ordered factor* (R's way of representing ordinal variables).  The predictor variables can be any combination of continuous (numeric) and categorical (factor) variables and their interactions ... can you point to documentation of your statement that `clmm`  "was designed to be used when response and predictor variables are factorial"?

Comment: In the R handbook and whatever examples we looked at there are only  factors predictors variable. Could you please provide a reference for clmm where it uses quantitative variable?

Comment: For StackOverflow (or for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), you need to make your questions clearer and more focused. Most of your comments have to do with testing the assumptions of ordinal regression (which is not the same as your question). Your second question is whether clmm supports numeric predictor variables. It does (e.g. see `vignette("clm_article")`, which simply says you need a vector of regression parameters. You can check https://rdrr.io/github/clbustos/rcebn/src/R/mi.mixed.ancova.analysis.ordinal.r for example.